# How to solve for the extrinsic variables of a one variable scaled conformal metric to an equivalent metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Given the following metric equivalence
\begin{align}
e^{2w(x_2)}
\left(
dx_1^2+dx_2^2
\right)
=
dy_1^2+dy_2^2+dy_3^2
\end{align}
is their a known solution for the extrinsic variables $y_1(x_1,x_2)$, $y_2(x_1,x_2)$ and $y_3(x_1,x_2)$? The scaling factor $e^{2w(x_2)}$ is only a function of $x_2$, not a function of both $x_1$ and $x_2$.

I know that the complex plane can be mapped to the surface of the Riemann sphere using the following metric
\begin{align}
\dfrac{4}{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}
\left(
dx_1^2+dx_2^2
\right)
=
dy_1^2+dy_2^2+dy_3^2
\end{align}
where
$x_1$ and $x_2$ are the complex variables of the complex plane and 
\begin{align}
y_3 = \dfrac{x_1^2+x_2^2-1}{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}
\\
y_2 = \dfrac{2x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}
\\
y_1 = \dfrac{2x_1}{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}
\end{align}
is the transformation to the extrinsic variables of the Riemann sphere $y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2=1$.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. I provided more information. Let me know if more is needed for clarification. I am still learning the proper vocabulary of higher level mathematics.

Comment: One more remark: the embedding problem is *very* different for positively curved and negatively curved surfaces. It's like elliptic PDE vs hyperbolic PDE. In your situation, the sign of curvature is determined by the sign of $w''$. If you have a particular $w$ in mind, is it convex or concave?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. I think in my case $e^{2w(x_2)}=\cos^{-2}(x_2)$. This means that $w(x_2)=-\ln(|\cos(x_2)|)$ and $w''(x_2) = \cos^{-2}(x_2)$, so it has positive curvature?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Using your suggested substitution of $z_1 + z_2 i = e^{x_1+x_2 i}$, my metric went under the following transformation $\cos^{-2}(x_2)(dx_1^2+dx_2^2) = (dz_1^2+dz_2^2)/z_1^2$.

Comment: The metric $\cos^{-2}(x_2)(dx_1^2+dx_2^2)$ is  singular when $\cos x_2 = 0 $. You can't even travel across this singularity in a curve of finite length. So you don't actually have a single surface, it's a bunch of identical surfaces, corresponding to $-\pi/2<x_2<\pi/2$. And for each piece, the singularity of the metric is about the same as for hyperbolic plane: it blows up $\approx $ proportionally  inverse distance to the boundary. This thing will not fit into $\mathbb R^3$, just as the hyperbolic plane does not fit there.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Using your suggested method of translating sheet in variance to phase in variance I solved the problem for all cases for $w(x_2)$. Where should I post the solution?

Comment: Post as an answer to this question, that's the natural place to put it. There's a button down on the page.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Thanks for the help. I posted the solution to this problem here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857306/how-to-improve-the-isometric-immersion-of-a-n-dimension-conformal-metric-of-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>tentative answer</sup>

Your question can be phrased as follows: given a metric of the form $e^{2w(x_2)}
\left( dx_1^2+dx_2^2 \right)$ on the plane, how to find an isometric immersion of this metric into $\mathbb R^3$? (An isometric immersion is a map $y=f(x)$ such that the relation in your post holds.)  One can also go further and ask for [isometric embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Riemannian_geometry). Either way, this is a difficult problem the study of which easily [fills a book](http://books.google.com/books?id=pHqOdaBCr2MC). E.g., it is still unknown whether every surface with $C^\infty$ smooth metric admits locally an isometric embedding into $\mathbb R^3$. Radially symmetric metrics $\exp(2w(x_1^2+x_2^2)) \left( dx_1^2+dx_2^2 \right)$ are easier to deal with, because one can look for a rotationally invariant surface in $\mathbb R^3$, thus reducing the problem from a difficult nonlinear PDE to an ODE. This works okay for metrics of positive curvature, but fails for negatively curved surfaces like the hyperbolic plane. (One can embed a piece of hyperbolic plane into $\mathbb R^3$ as a saddle-shaped surface, but this surface will not be rotationally symmetric despite the original metric being such.)

In your case, we have a different group of isometries acting on the surface: translations in the $x_1$ direction. Unfortunately we can't expect the image in $\mathbb R^3$ to also have translational invariance along $y_1$, because any such surface is of zero Gaussian curvature.

So, I expect that there is no explicit way to find a local embedding in general, and that a global embedding need not exist at all. One thing I would try:

1. Apply the exponential map $z=e^{x_2+ix_1}$, which is a local isometry of the given surface onto the plane with the radially symmetric metric $\frac{\exp(2 w(\log |z|))}{|z|^2}|dz|^2$
2. Use a radial stretch map in the plane to turn the metric into the form $dr^2+f(r)^2\,d\theta^2$.
3. Follow the ODE-based method as in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4166).

For a computational approach to the embedding problem, see [undergraduate paper by Sonya Kim](http://math.nyu.edu/degree/undergrad/Sonya%20Kim%20Impact%20Paper.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The more specific metric I ran into was $g=\cosh^{-2}(x_2)(dx_1^2-dx_2^2)$, which was hyperbolic. I was curious if one could solve for the the isometric immersion, however as you stated this is a very difficult problem.

Comment: I just realized that if I switch my metric from hyperbolic to euclidean $x_2 \rightarrow ix_2$, then I obtain the following metric $g = \cos^{-2}(x_2)(dx_1^2+dx_2^2)$, which displays a special type of phase in-variance?