# How to improve the isometric immersion of a $n$ dimension conformal metric of one variable conformal factor to be less than $2n-1$ dimensions?

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a conformal metric $ds^2 = \omega(x_n)(dx_1^2+dx_2^2+\cdots + dx_{n-1}^2+ dx_n^2)$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with conformal factor of one variable $\omega(x_n)$, does there exist an isometric immersion $ds^2 = (dy_1+dy_2+ \cdots)$ of $y_j \rightarrow y_j(x_i)$ in less than $2n-1$ dimensions?

Thanks to "This is much healthier." for helping me with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850374/how-to-solve-for-the-extrinsic-variables-of-a-one-variable-scaled-conformal-metr).

"This is much healthier." suggested that immersing each variable $x_j$ to be an angle in a polar coordinate system (complex variable) such that $y_j + i y_{j+n-1} = \rho_{j} e^{i x_j}$ would provide a solution to this problem. I continued with this idea and discovered a very simple solution of isometric immersing of the form

\begin{align}
ds^2 &=& (dy_1^2 + dy_{1+n-1}^2) + (dy_2^2 + dy_{2+n-1}^2) +\cdots +(dy_{n-1}^2 + dy_{2n-2}^2)+ (dy_{2n-1}^2)
\\
ds^2 &=& (d\rho_1^2 + \rho_1^2dx_{1}^2) + (d\rho_2^2 + \rho_2^2dx_{2}^2) +\cdots +(d\rho_{n-1}^2 + \rho_{n-1}^2dx_{n-1}^2)+ (dy_{2n-1}^2)
\\
\rho &=& \rho_1 = \rho_2 = \cdots = \rho_{n-1} 
\\
ds^2 &=& (d\rho^2 + \rho^2dx_{1}^2) + (d\rho^2 + \rho^2dx_{2}^2) +\cdots +(d\rho^2 + \rho^2dx_{n-1}^2)+ (dy_{2n-1}^2)
\\
ds^2 &=&
\rho^2
\left(
(dx_{1}^2) + (dx_{2}^2) + \cdots + (dx_{n-1}^2)
+
\left(
\dfrac{(n-1)d\rho^2 + dy_{2n-1}^2}{\rho^2}
\right)
\right)
\\
ds^2 &=& \omega(x_n)\left((dx_1^2)+(dx_2^2)+\cdots + (dx_{n-1}^2)+ (dx_n^2)\right)
\end{align}
where $\rho^2 = \omega(x_n)$ and

\begin{align}
\dfrac{(n-1)d\rho^2 + dy_{2n-1}^2}{\rho^2}
=
dx_n^2
\end{align}
which leads to the differential equation
\begin{align}
y_{2n-1}'(x_n)
=
\sqrt{
(\rho(x_n))^2
-
(n-1)
(\rho'(x_n))^2
}
.
\end{align}
If one uses the following conformal factor $\omega(x_n) = e^{f(x_n)}$, then
\begin{align}
y_{2n-1}'(x_n)
=
e^{f(x_n)}
\sqrt{
1
-
(n-1)
(f'(x_n))^2
}
.
\end{align}

This isometric immersion requires $2n-1$ dimensions. Is there away to condense $y_j$ to fewer dimensions?